# Connecting to load balancer on different protocols

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, protocols, amazon-elb

When connecting to an AWS load balancer I know each one has different protocols, e.g. Network Lb is TCP and UDP and Application Lb is Http/s, but is it written into the application code somewhere which protocol the app should connect with?

I’m in Devops and trying to better understand how these connections work as I’m looking to move away from Classic Lb

And so if I wanted to know if I should create an NLB or ALB, should I be asking developers which protocol the application uses to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 2):

Network Load Balancers (NLB) are Layer 4 load balancers, meaning that they can route TCP and UDP traffic. Since HTTP/HTTPS goes over TCP, NLBs can be used for HTTP/HTTPS traffic as well.

Application Load Balancer (ALB) are layer 7 load balancers, they can route HTTP/HTTPS traffic only (no bare TCP traffic, no UDP).

Although both ALB and NLB can route HTTP/HTTPS traffic, the difference between them is that ALB can understand the HTTP protocol, meaning that we can have routing rules based on HTTP headers, path variables, query params, etc. This is not possible if we are using NLBs, network load balancers can route based on source/destination IP and ports.

As a rule of thumb, use a ALBs if you have mainly web applications and you need all the features that a L7 load balancer can provide. Use NLB for anything else.